# Как умножить сумму денег на дробное число?

Tags: c++

Есть вариант:

```
class Money
{
private:
    unsigned long long rouble;
    unsigned char penny;
public:
Money operator *(const Money & m1, double m2)
{
    Money m_temp; 
    double rouble_float = m1.rouble + m1.kopek / 100; //преобразуем имеющиеся рубли с копейками в формат с плавающей точкой
    rouble_float *= m2; //умножаем пред. результат со вторым числом
    double integer; //создаём доп. переменную для хранения целой части числа с плавающей точкой. Она нужна для функции modf         
    m_temp.kopek = static_cast<unsigned char>(modf(rouble_float, &integer) * 100); //static_cast'ом говорим, что нам надо преобразовать тип double в тип unsigned char, т.е. отбрасываем точку. Умножаем на 100, т.к. хвост у нас дробный
    m_temp.rouble = static_cast<unsigned long long>(integer);        //то же самое, но уже для целой части (рубли)
    return m_temp;
}
```

Можно ли умножить без хранения денег в double или float? Если да, то как?

Comment: Непонятно, в чем проблема. Обычно суммы денег хранят в копейках, центах, сантимо и т.д. и перед выводом форматируют. Тогда таких проблем не возникает.

Comment: У меня целая часть суммы и копеечная часть суммы хранятся в отдельных переменных. (upd: дополнил код) @Эникейщик

Answer (score 4):

Делайте наоборот - не копейки делить на 100, а рубли умножать, тогда получится целое число.

```
Money operator *(const Money & m1, double m2)
{
    Money m_temp; 
    long amount= m1.rouble *100 + m1.kopek; // сумма в копейках
    amount *= m2; 
    и дальше разделяйте результат на рубли и копейки как вам нравится.
}
```

Но вообще более правильный подход изначально хранить денежные суммы в копейках и тогда не возникает проблем с дробными числами.

Comment: Если так делать, то мы не теряем наши копейки? В long положили сумму в рублёвом виде, далее умножили целое число на дробную, получили целую?

Comment: Сумма лежит в копейках (см. комментарий в коде). Теряются доли копеек, но они теряютя в любом случае. Можно сумму в копейках положить в double, умножать, а потом разделять на целые рубли и копейки. Так будет _немного_ точнее для некоторых данных.

Comment: "Точнее" в данном случае означает выигрыш в точности максимум в одну копейку.

Answer (score 2):

Я не очень понял Вас, но почему нельзя сделать так:

```
Money operator *(const Money & m1, double m2)
{
    double rubl_part = ((double) m1.rouble) * m2*100;
    double kopey_part = ((double) m1.kopek) *m2;

    double sum = rubl_part+kopey_part;

    //Дальше Ваши преобразования
    Money m_temp; 

    m_temp.rouble = static_cast<unsigned long long>(sum/100);  

    m_temp.kopek = static_cast<unsigned char>(sum-m_temp.rouble*100); 

    return m_temp;
}
```

Пишу с мобилы из метро, поэтому код не проверял, но мне кажется что это проще, чем Ваш исходный вариант.

Comment: Так нельзя делать, потому что вы складываете рубли с копейками и вместо 15 рублей 50 копеек у вас получится 65 неизвестно чего.

Comment: @Эникейщик, угу :) , но в вагоне очень сложно быть внимательным - щас поправлю :)